# RewriteCond exclude specific folders and HashTag

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with a rewrite Condition.

I need to add a Parameter (service=xy) to all URL.

Except if the URL Contains the folder /folder1, /folder2, a Hashtag or already has the parameter (service=xy).

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?i)(?!service|#)
RewriteCond %{REQUEUST_URI} !^(/folder1|/folder2)$
RewriteRule $ ?service=xy [L,R,QSA]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't detect the "hashtag" (`#`) server-side since the browser does not send this to the server (assuming you mean an _unencoded_ hash). Is this critical to your requirements?

Comment: We have two links with "hashtag" (#) on the page, and the rule to add the parameter should not apply to them. Because this will break the anchor functionality.
But they link to a different subfolder as well, is it possible to make an exception if a specific subfolder is part of the url, not to add the parameter. But do so in every other case?

Comment: Yes, you can make an exception for a specific subfolder. What is the subfolder/URL format? Is it just a second level directory? In your question you state "Contains the folder /folder1, /folder2" - although the rule you are using is testing "starts with", not "contains"? (Although you also have a typo in that condition.)

Comment: It's a complete different url. Yes, it should be 'contain', not 'start with'.
The rule is on page: /lang/url1 and links to /lang/folderx/folder1/#abc

Comment: "or already has the parameter (service=xy)" - specifically with the value `xy`? So, if `service=ab` is present then you need to override this? "The rule is on page: /lang/url1 and links to /lang/folderx/folder1/#abc" - what do you mean by "The rule is on page: /lang/url1"? Presumably the exception applies to `/lang/folderx/folder1/`?